# How to acquire actor reference to typed actor implementation in Akka?

Tags: scala, akka

For Akka 2.2 how do I get a reference to a TypedActor. For untyped Actors we are advised to use ActorSelection and then use tell on ActorSelection. What should I do for TypedActor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use typed actors, but I'm going to take a shot at answering this question anyway based on the documentation and a little guess work.  I don't believe Typed Actors and `ActorSelection`s work directly together.  If you think about an `ActorSelection`, it's really a proxy to 0 to many actual `ActorRef`s that match whatever query was used in the `actorSelection` call that yielded it.  This selection works well with untyped actors in cases where you want to broadcast the same message to a set of actors.  Sitting a typed proxy in front of this seems to make less sense as I can't think of a ton of use cases where you want narrowed typing and to broadcast to a set of possible destinations and potentially receive responses (i.e. `ask`).

Now, if you have an `ActorSelection`, and you want to query that selection for a single ref under it (by using either `Identify` or `resolveOne`) and you get back an `ActorRef`, then you can snap a typed actor proxy in front of it like so:

```
  val typedActor = 
    TypedActor(system).typedActorOf(TypedProps[MyTypedActor],myLookedUpRef)
```

This technique basically takes a looked up untyped actor and narrows it into a `TypedActor` that you can now communicate with via the `TypedActor`s interface.

You can read more about `TypedActor`s [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/typed-actors.html) and more about resolving `ActorSelection`s [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/actors.html#actorselection-scala).

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. I did not realize that when you pass `ActorRef` to `typedActorOf` it narrows it down to required type. The only problem is that to acquire `ActorRef` you have to do `resolveOne()` on selection and being an asynchronous operation it requires a bit of code. I found the following ticket with the link to a discussion on google groups: [link](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/3716?comment=419485183). After comparing amount of code needed for to use `TypedActor` vs simple `actorSelect ! msg` makes you think twice if to use typed actors at all.

Comment: Yes, one should think twice before using TypedActors over normal ones.